# What should I consider when moving a project using Entity Framework 6 from SQL Server to MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Tags: entity-framework, onion-architecture

First, I need to confess this question come mostly from the still expensive licensing model used by Microsoft for SQL Server Standard. Also because Web edition is now only available through Web Hosting provider. For information: it's 1 license per 2 CPU Core + CAL per user.

From a Microsoft sales contact I spoke with yesterday: between 550 and 800 € (note the incredible difference depending on reseller and I guess volume : 250 € near 50%) per 2 Core + between 280 and 293 € per user.

So if we could easily move our data From SQL Server to any open source engine (MySQL, PostgreSQL or NoSQL like Redis) we do love spend this money in time to learn new skills instead of giving it to Microsoft for a system oversized for our needs. When I write oversized I refer to the other functionality included in Standard Edition instead of Web Edition (SSRS, SSAS, etc. ...)

Our software architecture is an [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/files/media/image/WindowsLiveWriter/TheOnionArchitecturepart1_70A9/image%7B0%7D%5B59%5D.png) as proposed by [Jeffrey Pallermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) back in 2008:

[image: Onion Architecture in MVC]

As you can see from the picture it was used with MVC in mind. We used it with Web API 2 which share the same kind of philosophy.

We rely on [SOLID principles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-Architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp) as long as we have time to do it well. So we used dependency injection with per request instance using Ioc Container Autofac. Each controller Action mostly speaks to Core layer Domain services by giving them the correct `IEntityRepository` implementation resolved when the controller is instantiated during Asp.Net request life cycle. So in theory, we only have dependencies over IEntityRepository interface wich does it's job as "Contract":

```
 public interface IWriteBaseRepository<TEntity> : IReadBaseRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Add(TEntity entity);

    IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);

    TEntity AddOrUpdate(TEntity entity);

    IEnumerable<TEntity> AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    void SaveChanges();

    IEnumerable<string> GetPendingChanges(TEntity entity, string identifierPropertyName, Dictionary<string, string> includeProperties = null);
}
```

For the repository part we used Code First approach and there absolutely no intelligence in the DB (thanks to [Uncle Bob](https://8thlight.com/blog/patrick-gombert/2016/04/18/deferring-database.html) for his clear views). Our Repositories mostly return DbSet as IEnumerable. So You may have guessed we strongly use lazy loading by kind of "Transitivity" in our Domain Services.

So knowing the few I wrote and your past experience on shifting from a DB engine to an other, any feedback would be much appreciate before I find the courage to dive deep in PostgreSQL which remind me not so easy couple of hours on my first try of Oracle back in 2002.

Comment: What's the question again ?

Comment: @Machabo as in the title : Replacing SQL Server used with entity framework by any open source engine. Fell free to edit the question if my english (not my mother tongue) is not good enough.

Comment: does EF support MySQL? answer: yes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: How much data do you have?  You can always try express.

Comment: @Ewan thanks I already had a look at other open source RDBS supported by EF. My needs is more on concrete experience feedback in similar case of switching from SQL Server to another open source solution

Comment: And FYI, you get what you pay for.

Comment: @Matthew we know for sure we will exceed 10 GB so express is not a good fit

Comment: @GuillaumeRAYMOND, still, I'd like to help you asking the correct question, by trying to understand better the problem. Are you asking whether EF has support to other DBMS engines ? Do you have already in scope what DBs you want to support in your application ? Do you want to know what to avoid when creating a multi-DBMS capable application ? Narrow it a little down. The question, as is, is just too broad, give us a little more information to help ask the correct question.

Comment: Are you using any advanced features in SQL server? (SSB, SSIS, SSRS, SSAS ...)  If you are just using it as a place to store data from your application and you aren't doing any special on the server side you can easily change over to another SQL DB like MySQL, postgresql or even Oracle.  You can even change over to one of the many nosql DBs.

Comment: @Mattew and Machado you make me fell my english is damn awfull. By the way I will edit my question with your remarks to try to stop this to be down voting :(

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Postgresql is reliable, industrial-strength,and unencumbered by copyleft.  The documentation is first-class.  About the only thing it doesn't provide is phone support, but in 20 years of working with SQL Server I haven't had to call Microsoft once.  I would expect the same level of reliability from Postgres.

Comment: It also doesn't have many features that MS SQL has that I use in many of my projects.  But if you are just sticking data in columns it doesn't matter what you use.  (I typically do data first designs so I don't even like the new direction for EF)

Comment: Also, trying to the to the point of the question, if you use the DBMS **just** as a data repository, without any vendor-specific features, I don't see why you'd have any problem using either SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Postgresql, MySQL or any other thing supported by Entity Framework. Remembering that even small things, like an Identity Column in a table may be described as vendor-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary concerns are:

1. Finding a way to make your existing `IQueryable` Linq queries compatible with Postgres.
2. Working through any vendor differences in the SQL statements and database features you are using.
3. Finding substitutes for vendor-specific capabilities that you're using in SQL Server that are not present in Postgres.

For your `IQueryable` provider, I would have a look at [dotConnect for PostGresql](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html).